# Invalid request, No data was found Roudcube

Tags: php, imap, dovecot, exim, roundcube

I am currently facing to issue with Roundcube.
1)The first one is with OS compatibility when I use RoundCube in OS like CentOS or Ubuntu it's the usage count proper but when I use Almalinux or Cloudlinux it shows unknown instead of Usage calculation.
2)The second one is with `roundcube_sessid` I am using two SQLite DB at a time whenever the user is on the login page I am using the default DB for all the Email users but while posting the data I am justifying their DB path with the login Credentials. And I am getting `Invalid Request, No Data was saved` error. This is only happening in CentOS and Ubuntu Server but when I use Almulinux for the same it is working properly.

Any solution regarding this.
Thanks in advance.